WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials\ncaused by: SerializationError: failed to unmarshal error message\n\tstatus code: 405 , Loki Helm
I'm deploying Loki in an EKS cluster using an S3 bucket for storage. I've configured IAM Roles for Service Accounts (IRSA) to allow Loki to access the S3 bucket. However, I'm encountering the following error in the Loki logs:
WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials\ncaused by: SerializationError: failed to unmarshal error message\n\tstatus code: 405

Whole error looks like this:

level=error ts=2024-11-14T10:08:39.203006213Z caller=flush.go:261
component=ingester loop=1 org_id=1 msg="failed to flush" retries=2
err="failed to flush chunks: store put chunk: WebIdentityErr: failed
to retrieve credentials\ncaused by: SerializationError: failed to
unmarshal error message\n\tstatus code: 405, request id: \ncaused by:
UnmarshalError: failed to unmarshal error message\n\t00000000  3c 3f
78 6d 6c 20 76 65  72 73 69 6f 6e 3d 22 31  |.<C|\n00000030  6f 64 65 3e 0d 65 74 68
6f 64 4e 6f 74 41 6c 6c  |ode>MethodNotAll|\n00000040  6f 77 65 64 3c
2f 43 6f  64 65 3e 3c 4d 65 73 73  |owed<Mess|\n00000050  61 67
65 3e 54 68 65 20  73 70 65 63 69 66 69 65  |age>The
specifie|\n00000060  64 20 6d 65 74 68 6f 64  20 69 73 20 6e 6f 74 20
|d method is not |\n00000070  61 6c 6c 6f 77 65 64 20  61 67 61 69 6e
73 74 20  |allowed against |\n00000080  74 68 69 73 20 72 65 73  6f 75
72 63 65 2e 3c 2f  |this resource.</|\n00000090  4d 65 73 73 61 67 65
3e  3c 4d 65 74 68 6f 64 3e  |Message>|\n000000a0  50 4f 53 54
3c 2f 4d 65  74 68 6f 64 3e 3c 52 65  |POST<Re|\n000000b0  73
6f 75 72 63 65 54 79  70 65 3e 53 45 52 56 49
|sourceType>SERVI|\n000000c0  43 45 3c 2f 52 65 73 6f  75 72 63 65 54
79 70 65  |CE</ResourceType|\n000000d0  3e 3c 52 65 71 75 65 73  74 49
64 3e 45 36 50 34  |>E6P4|\n000000e0  34 34 34 43 51 32 4e
30  35 45 52 4a 3c 2f 52 65  |444CQ2N05ERJ</Re|\n000000f0  71 75 65 73
74 49 64 3e  3c 48 6f 73 74 49 64 3e  |questId>|\n00000100  70
4f 30 35 58 6d 42 4b  33 6d 45 36 30 43 32 66
|pO05XmBK3mE60C2f|\n00000110  6c 56 74 36 76 65 45 36  37 41 6c 56 43
58 4a 4d  |lVt6veE67AlVCXJM|\n00000120  61 9c 66 39 65 50 36 67  56 53
7a 70 57 49 78 50  |aLf9eP6gVSzpWIxP|\n00000130  57 32 32 63 58 76 51
51  73 6b 54 6b 35 78 64 6d  |W22cXvQQskTk5xdm|\n00000140  62 52 6b 36
35 73 48 33  4e 39 2f 54 6e 39 77 30  |bRk65sH3N9/Tn9w0|\n00000150  46
72 31 2f 2f 75 61 55  34 6d 2b 78 64 6f 46 59
|Fr1//uaU4m+xdoFY|\n00000160  71 7a 6e 47 79 86 35 51  4a 2b 59 3d 3c
2f 48 6f  |qznGyF5QJ+Y=</Ho|\n00000170  73 74 49 64 3e 3c 2f 45  72 72
6f 72 3e           |stId>|\n\ncaused by: unknown error
response tag, {{ Error} []}, num_chunks: 1, labels:
{app="curl-test", container="curl-test",
filename="/var/log/pods/default_curl-test_5cb0fb1b-922b-4a1c-b8e0-e6506bec3cee/curl-test/239.log",
job="default/curl-test", namespace="default",
node_name="ip-172-32-18-62.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal",
pod="curl-test", service_name="curl-test", stream="stdout"}"

This is my loki-values.yml:
loki:
  auth-enabled: false
  image:
    tag: 3.2.1
  schemaConfig:
    configs:
      - from: "2024-04-01"
        store: tsdb
        object_store: s3
        schema: v13
        index:
          prefix: loki_index_
          period: 24h
  
  annotations: 
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::469030223850:role/loki-test-role-again

  storage_config:
    aws:
      # s3: s3://ap-southeast-1/chunks-buck
      region: ap-southeast-1
      bucketnames: chunks-buck
      s3forcepathstyle: false

  pattern_ingester:
      enabled: true

  limits_config:
    allow_structured_metadata: true
    volume_enabled: true
    retention_period: 672h # 28 days retention
  querier:
    max_concurrent: 4

  storage:
    bucketNames:
      chunks: chunks-buck
      ruler: ruler-buck
      admin: admin-buck
    type: s3
    s3:
      s3: s3://ap-southeast-1/chunks-buck
      endpoint: s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
      region: ap-southeast-1
      s3ForcePathStyle: false

  memcached:
    chunk_cache:
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 500m
          memory: 256Mi  # Lower memory request
      limits:
        memory: 512Mi  # Lower memory limit

deploymentMode: SimpleScalable

serviceAccount:
  # -- Specifies whether a ServiceAccount should be created
  create: true
  # -- The name of the ServiceAccount to use.
  # If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the fullname template
  name: loki-sa
  # -- Image pull secrets for the service account
  imagePullSecrets: []
  # -- Labels for the service account
  labels: {}
  # -- Annotations for the service account
  annotations: 
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::469030223850:role/loki-test-role-again
  # -- Set this toggle to false to opt out of automounting API credentials for the service account
  automountServiceAccountToken: true


backend:
  replicas: 3
  persistence:
    volumeClaimsEnabled: false

read:
  replicas: 3
  persistence:
    storageClass: gp2

write:
  replicas: 3
  persistence:
    volumeClaimsEnabled: false
# --  Configuration for the read pod(s)
minio:
  enabled: false

singleBinary:
  persistence:
    storageClass: gp2

ingestor:
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 512Mi
    limits:
      memory: 1Gi

  persistence:
    claims:
      - name: data
        storageClass: gp2

querier:
  persistence:
    storageClass: gp2

indexGateway:
  persistence:
    storageClass: gp2

compactor:
  persistence:
    storageClass: gp2
    claims:
      - name: data
        storageClass: gp2

bloomGateway:
  persistence:
    claims:
      - name: data
        storageClass: gp2

bloomPlanner:
  persistence:
    claims:
      - name: data
        storageClass: gp2

patternIngester:
  persistence:
    storageClass: gp2
    claims:
      - name: data
        storageClass: gp2

ruler:
  persistence:
    storageClass: gp2
  
resultsCache:
  persistence:
    storageClass: gp2

chunksCache:
  allocatedMemory: 1000
  persistence:
    storageClass: gp2

Chart Name: grafana/loki
Chart Version: 6.19.0

This solution worked for me: https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/issues/1550. I uncommented the endpoint in the values.yml file or simply removed it.
Make sure you have specified the correct ARN and annotations in the values.yml file and have permissions to access the bucket.
